# What is the most pythonic way to create a 'For Loop' that filters through a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am looking to search for and then append an item through a dictionary (named: songs) that contains a list of tracks. However, this dictionary has multiple levels and indices. Here is my code:

```
artists = []

for i in range(len(songs['tracks'])):
     artist.append(songs['tracks'][i]['artists'][0]['name'])
```

Is there a more pythonic way of writing this code? I feel as though using 
`in range(len(songs['tracks']))` is not the best way to achieve this, but it does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution equivalent to your code may be

```
artists = [track['artists'][0]['name'] for track in songs['tracks']]
```

Comment: The indentation was an error. I adjusted. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, what you're doing there is actually a "map" operation (transforming the items of one array into another array/list), not a "filter" operation (removing certain items that match a condition from an array/list).

Second, you shouldn't be looping over a range. This is a `for in` loop, not a traditional `for` loop, so there's no index. Instead, each iteration contains the item in the list/array.

```
artists = []
for track in songs['tracks']:
    artists.append(track['artists'][0]['name'])
```

You can turn this into a one liner using [list comprehensions](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html). They take the common premise of iterating over a list to create a new list, possibly transforming the results and possibly filtering the results. The syntax they use is:

```
result = [ <transformation> for item in items if <condition> ]
```

In your case you don't have an explicit need for a condition since you're simply mapping one set of array values to another, like this:

```
artists = [ track[artists][0]['name'] for track in songs['tracks'] ]
```

However, if you were filtering, that if condition would be what you'd use. For example

```
artists_with_long_songs = [ track[artists][0]['name'] for track in songs['tracks'] if track['length'] > 600 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation. This will definitely help me out!